# Dental deep cleaning recommendation without probing?

Tags: dentistry

I've had dentists in the past use a measurement tool to measure the "pockets" of my gums to make the determination that I need a "deep cleaning," yet I've had other dentists skip that measurement and just make the same conclusion based on the x-rays alone.

Are x-rays alone sufficient for recommending this procedure? If so, can someone describe what one would look for? Bonus points if you can put up a side by side "healthy" and "needs treatment" x-ray examples.

Comment: I will preface this by admitting I am not a dentist, but I think this question will be challenging to answer because we cannot define what a "deep cleaning" is. I suspect there are different procedures that individual dentists consider to be a deep cleaning. Additionally, questions on this website are required to demonstrate some prior research. Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried thus far and the results of those searches.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, questions here are required to demonstrate some degree of prior research. The answer to this question is immediately available if you google the terms `periodontal disease x-ray`.